# 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' issue

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, access-control

I have an angular frontend with a rails backend.

I have angular code like this:

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: 'http://localhost:3000/products.json'}).
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
     $scope.data = data;
  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
     $scope.status = status;
});
```

I kept getting the `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4000' is therefore not allowed access.` error, so I used https://stackoverflow.com/a/17815546/561634 so my config/application.rb has:

```
config.action_dispatch.default_headers = {
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*',
  'Access-Control-Request-Method' => '*'
}
```

inside it. Unfortunately, this hasn't changed the error.

Thanks for all help!

Comment: Which site you set that?
If site1 call ajax request to site2, you should set it on site1. For this annoying problem, I gave up to set that config, I use jsonp now. You can also try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mare sure you don't have an error on your back-end that would cause an "500 - Internal server error" because in that case the "Access-Control" headers may not be send.