# For CORS Error Do i need to configure on client side(Angular js) also?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ajax, cors

**Error:XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://thirdPartyasite/template.html. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.**

I am using Rails application which is consuming Cross orgin data through ajax call.The answers Provided by this question not working.

1)[How to set access-control-allow-origin in webrick under rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535454/how-to-set-access-control-allow-origin-in-webrick-under-rails)

2)https://demisx.github.io/rails-api/2014/02/18/configure-accept-headers-cors.html

3)[Allow anything through CORS Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17858178/allow-anything-through-cors-policy).

I dont have control over the client app.How to overcome this problem.

I tried This one:

```
before_filter :set_headers
  def set_headers
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, PUT, DELETE, GET, OPTIONS'
    headers['Access-Control-Request-Method'] = '*'
     headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization'
  end
```

[image: My Response]

Still the same error is coming.

**Tried This also:**
In gem file added:`gem 'rack-cors', :require => 'rack/cors'`
In config/application.rb:

```
config.middleware.insert_before 0, "Rack::Cors" do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :options]
  end
end
```

Still Getting same error.

**Work Around For Dev Environment:**
Install CORS Chrome plugin.
But I need Proper Solution

Comment: You may need to post some code (what you have done so far that is not working).

Comment: @LeonelMachavaI updated My question with what I tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular $sceDelegateProvider can throw exception while you sourcing Angular templates with CORS. For more read [sceDelegateProvider official documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$sceDelegateProvider)

For testing purposes you can use this:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).config(function($sceDelegateProvider) {
  $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
        'self',
        'http://**',
        'https://**'
  ]);
});
```

Comment: This Might be the issue I am requesting for angular template only. But I dont have access to That code I let People know regarding this and I will try

Comment: I got a chance to walk through the code They have configured only certain number of whitelist url.Thanks For the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to configure anything on Angular.

To enable CORS you just configure the server as you see in the links to the answers you posted.

Comment: I tried Every thing but still it throwing error But the headers got added in Response.

Answer (score 0):

[CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) is a server-side constraint only.

If you have access to your Rails app, you'll be best using the [`Rack-CORS`](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors) gem to enabled specific resources/origins:

```
#config/application.rb
...
  config.middleware.insert_before 0, "Rack::Cors" do
    allow do
      origins '*'
      resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :options]
    end
  end
```

If you *don't* have access to your server-side rails app, you need to gain access, otherwise it won't work.